# Pay event fee with paypal and allow guests

Tags: php, paypal

I have been hunting around developer.paypal.com for a couple of days now and have the gist of what I need.  But I am still looking on the best way to accomplish my task.

What I need is a way for people to pay a fee for an event from my website.  I would prefer to allow Guest Checkout as not all attendees will likely have a paypal account yet.  But what I would really like is for the paypal website to handle all of checkout.  In ebay, you see the total, a small summary and you pay for it right there.  I have looked at express checkout, and it wants to return the user to my website to finalize everything.

So in short:
Allow guest checkout
Show payment total on Paypal webpage
Allow payment to be finalized and 'Captured' from PayPal's website, only coming back to my page to say Thanks.
And if possible, not require an address of the attendee

Can this be done? 
I have long used StackOverflow for answers, but I am having a hard time finding this answer (mainly because I don't know exactly what I am looking for).

Thanks in advance

Comment: This can be done. You calculate the sum on your website and then send this number to the paypal servers. You will need to set up a merchant ID etc. Paypal then carry out the payment process then send the customer, with info to a page you have set up. The info you receive from paypal will determine wether you send the customer to an error page or a confirmation page. the customer never sees this transfer page, it is done instantly, if you write it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Express Checkout is the most robust API to use.  The "return" to your site is a good thing, to give the customer the ability to click a final "Place Order" button.  But you can also have this triggered automatically on return -- just run DoExpressCheckout without user interaction and display a thank you / confirmation message.  If you are going to run DoEC w/o interaction, your initial redirect to PayPal.com should have &useraction=commit appended to the URL.  Then, the final button at PayPal.com will say "Pay Now" instead of the default "Continue"

To allow guest checkout with EC, pass SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole in the initial SetEC call.  Note that when customers load a PayPal.com checkout page, it checks their browser cookies to see if they have a PayPal email address stored.  If they have one stored in the browser, the top "Log in to PayPal" section will be expanded.  If they do not have an address stored -- generally meaning this is a brand new computer or they've never used a PayPal account to check out on this one before -- then the bottom guest checkout section will be expanded.

To not require an address, pass NOSHIPPING=1.

Comment: This makes a lot of good sense and I like this idea.  I have been playing with this to try and get a feel for those options:
https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/PayPalAPIs

But there are many times that it just hangs.  I'll keep playing with this part and see if I can just write my own requests with cURL and see what I get.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing "standard", and the HTML button integration will be much easier than Express Checkout.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it looks like it has the possibility of working slick.  My issue now is getting IPN working which looks like it might be a little complicated as well.  Is this the only method for finding out if they successfully checked out?  I know I can specify the return URLs, but is there a way of identifying the person at that URL along with the form data they had submitted just before?

Comment: Looks like I can specify the return URL in the HTML code.  I think what I might do is have it submit the form into a database before going to paypal and then have it mark it paid when it returns to a randomly generated URL to update the SQL entry to say paid.

Comment: The customer's browser may not return for whatever reason.  If they pay as a guest with Standard, PayPal is obligated to show them a receipt and they must actually click to return.  If they pay with a PayPal account they will be automatically redirected after 10 seconds, but what if their browser crashes?  Your SQL entry would never get mark as paid in these scenarios.  You could implement IPN as a separate notification system, but at that point you are doing enough work that you should have just used Express Checkout to begin with.  It's a better integration.

Comment: That is a good point.  So how about this.  I use the Express Checkout, save the form and information in the database along with the Token that is generated.  Then if they return at the end of paying, my website will check on the payment using the token generated and mark it paid if successful.  And then if I have tokens that were generated, but never came back, would I use a cron job to check all the remaining tokens for their status?  And idea how long I can look up a token for after it has been created?  I'll play with this idea, just writing it here to get some input.  Thanks so far!